# Does ubuntu OS time settings update with daylight savings?

Tags: 14.04, time

We use ubuntu docker containers in production.

We need to ensure, that time(`time.Now().UTC()` in GoLang) given by OS reflects daylight savings(when needed)

Does ubuntu OS clock time, update with  daylight savings?

Comment: I don't think that daylight haven't is defined for UTC. But most other timezones has.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If you selected a time zone or region that observes DST, the clock will automatically adjust.

Comment: Is daylight savings defined for UTC as well?

Comment: It's defined in the fact that UTC doesn't change for DST

Comment: Hmm...I'm on NYT / Eastern time zone & we just entered DST & my computer has not accounted for this today, even though we are 2 days past it.